# How to enter ADSR envelope on BOSS SY-300

Tags: guitar-effects, synthesizer, synthesis

I'm trying to program a simple Attack Delay Sustain Release (ADSR) envelope on my BOSS SY-300 guitar synthesizer but the menus are way confusing and the documentation almost non-existent.

What I understand so far is that I need to be in the OSC Wave/Pitch and Filter/Amp pages of a patch but what knobs to tweak I'm confused about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this manual](https://medias.audiofanzine.com/files/sy-300-parameter-guide-sound-list-474551.pdf), which seems to be a bit more complete on settings than the owner's manual:

It seems that you cannot really define a full ADSR envelope on the SY-300 however you might have some success to achieve what you want by tweaking:

- the compressor attack and sustain level (page 6), which will allow you to give you sound a slower envelope than the picking sound (long attack, but also the sustain),
- and maybe the amp env attack (page 4),
- for the release, if you want a slower/longer release than the original sound, maybe the reverb can help, but unfortunately there are no dedicated parameters here…

Not much of an answer but hope it might help…

Comment: Looking for a shorter release than the original.  It's crazy that there isn't a straightforward ADSR interface.

Comment: @pro I agree, but the problem I think it's that it's not using the guitar sound as a real gate signal... I would say that the amp env attack should be symmetric: if you put it very high, the amp will be very dependent on the guitar level, maybe more than linear that would indeed make shorter attack and release. Then you can get the attack back right by playing with the comp... Maybe?